# Web API Scaffold Controller From Model In Referenced Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, scaffolding

When trying to create Controller from Visual Studio, I can get most types that exist in the application's assembly but how to Scaffold Controllers based on types in a referenced assembly?

For example: MyApp.API will reference a separate assembly MyApp.Model that contains POCOs.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in VS 2013 scafolding works for referenced assembly as for other.
I use it everyday and everything works.
Just a tip :

- add your reference
- add your referenced entities to your DbSet
- perform a migration if you use them, or simply rebuild your application
- ask for scafolding.

Scafolding works well **only** if everything is built properly.

Comment: The assembly I am referencing already has POCO and `DbContext` in it. I also tried rebuilding and app is set on automatic migrations. I used `update-database` just to be sure but still no detection of my models in the separate assembly in Controller scaffolding.